# Wordpress: Creating a dynamic checkbox group using a post loop in functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress, checkbox, custom-post-type

Thank you for taking the time to read this, I'll explain best I can. Any help is appreciated.

I have a checkbox group available for me to use for each of my Wordpress posts. It allows me to tick/check which people are featured in the current post. I achieved this by adding this code to my functions.php file:

```
function add_custom_meta_box() {
add_meta_box(
    'custom_meta_box',
    'Featured People',
    'show_custom_meta_box',
    'post',
    'side',
    'core'
);}

add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'add_custom_meta_box');

// Field Array

$prefix = 'custom_';
$custom_meta_fields = array(

array (
'label' => '',
'desc'  => '',
'id'    => $prefix.'checkbox_group',
'type'  => 'checkbox_group',
'options' => array (
    '1' => array (
        'label' => 'Person One',
        'value' => 'personone'
    ),
    '2' => array (
        'label' => 'Person Two',
        'value' => 'persontwo'
    ),
    '3' => array (
        'label' => 'Person Three',
        'value' => 'personthree'
    ),  
    '4' => array (
        'label' => 'Person Four',
        'value' => 'personfour'

    // Add More People Here

    ),
)
)
);
```

This works all fine, however, I'm sure you'll agree that it would be very tedious to keep adding people each time there's a new person.

So, in an attempt to make this checkbox group more dynamic, I created a new custom post type that allows me to add the information for each person the same way you would add the content for a normal post in wp-admin. The only problem is I can't figure out how to loop through this custom post type in functions.php.

This is what I want to do:

```
array (
   'label' => '',
   'desc'  => '',
   'id'    => $prefix.'checkbox_group',
   'type'  => 'checkbox_group',
   'options' => array (

$args = array( 
   'post_type' => 'featured-people',        //LOOP THROUGH THIS POST TYPE
   'posts_per_page' => -1 );
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();

      'the_title();' => array (             //FOR EACH, DO THIS
          'label' => 'the_title();',  
          'value' => 'the_value();'   
      ),

endwhile
```

I'm hoping to make this post type populate the checkbox group, and each time a new person is added, the checkbox group will update to include them as an option.

(I then have to figure out how to display the information on single.php, but one thing at a time).

Any help would be greatly appriciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You were pretty darn close. The easiest way is to store the options in a variable, do the loop, then do the rest. This should get you started:

```
///store options
$options = array();

$args = array( 
   'post_type' => 'featured-people',
   'posts_per_page' => -1 
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );


//loop query
while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
      //get_the_title returns the post title
      //bracket notation stores it as the array key
      $options[get_the_title()] => array (         

          'label' => get_the_title(),  

          //get post meta's last parameter decides if it is a string
          //might need to play with this part a bit
          'value' => get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'custom_meta_box' true)   

      );

endwhile;

$custom_meta_fields = array(
    array (
        'label' => '',
        'desc'  => '',
        'id'    => $prefix.'checkbox_group',
        'type'  => 'checkbox_group',
        'options' => $options //reference our previous array
    )
);
```

**EDIT**

You could technically create a self-invoking function with `call_user_func` if you want the wanted to do the logic 'inline', although it's a bit of an odd pattern:

```
$custom_meta_fields = array(
    array (
        'label' => '',
        'desc'  => '',
        'id'    => $prefix.'checkbox_group',
        'type'  => 'checkbox_group',
        'options' => call_user_func(function(){                 
               ///store options
               $options = array();

               $args = array( 
                   'post_type' => 'featured-people',
                   'posts_per_page' => -1 
               );

               $query = new WP_Query( $args );
               //loop query
               while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
                     $options[get_the_title()] => array (         
                         'label' => get_the_title(),  
                         'value' => get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'custom_meta_box' true)   
                     );
               endwhile;

               return $options;

        })
    )
);
```

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately, still no luck. Your solution is obviously much easier and cleaner than what I was trying to do before, but what was the issue with my method? Is it even possible with my method? Thanks.

Comment: @Bryce could you be more specific as to what's not working? I also don't really understand what you mean by 'your method'. Do you mean executing the while loop inside the array declaration (which will throw a fatal error)?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean, thank you for clearing that up. I'll give it another go and have another tinker, but my previous attempts yielded yet another fatal error.

Comment: @Bryce I updated my answer to have an 'inline' option after my original answer. What does the fatal error say? Could you post it?

Comment: Thank you for your patience and help. Why is $options an empty array? Or isn't it? Shouldn't it be the loop itself?

Comment: @Bryce it is an empty array at the beginning (for storing the upcoming values) that gets populated by the while loop, then returned to your outer array. You can see the line `$options[get_the_title()]...` where each option gets added in.

Comment: Everything is fine until I add in the options to the loop. If I remove everything from the loop and leave it empty, I have no error.

Comment: Apologies, I didn't initially see you ask for the fatal error. It states there's a syntax error with the `=>` after `$options[get_the_title()]`

Comment: Ah, that is my mistake. Should be = instead of => @Bryce

Comment: Okay, we're getting somewhere! No more fatal error! @Jesse, you're a legend. There was also a comma missing before `true` in the `'value'` line. Just have to fix up something that seems to be conflicting with my checkbox group lower down in my functions.php causing no values to show in said group when inputting values in wp-admin. Will post full solution when I get it working fully, for people in the future doing this kind of thing.